# Is it possible to add new app variables on iPhone, similar to ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}?

Tags: iphone, application-settings

I'd like to reference my own variables in my info.plist & build settings files.

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you add custom build settings via the 'add build setting' button in the bottom right, then you should be able to use the ${} form within your info.plist to reference the names of those variables.

For example, I have such a setting called 'PJ_VERSION_EXTRA'. In my Info.plist I have:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.1${PJ_VERSION_EXTRA}</string>
```

In my debug build configuration, I define that setting as '-DEBUG'. That means that when I show the version string in app, debug builds identify themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I can see any problems with doing this.

Should be as simple as adding an entry to the info plist, and then retrieving it using

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:myPlistKeyName];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but perhaps my question wasn't so clear... I actually want to use a variable in the info.plist file itself, similar to how the ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} variable is often used.

Comment: Oh I see... Try looking through the Build Settings reference guide, you might find an answer there (requires login) https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/Xcode_Build_Settings.pdf